# Axioms of motion (Redei version)

Tags: geometry, axioms, foundations

I try to understand the axioms of motion in Redei's "Foundationd of Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries, according to F. Klein" 1968

Redei gives as Axioms:

1. Any motion is a one to one mapping of space R onto itself such that every three points on a line will be transformed into (three) points on a line.
2. The identical mapping of space R is a motion.
3. The product of two motions is a motion.
4. The inverse mapping of a motion is a motion.
5. If we have two planes A, A' two lines g, g' and two points P, P' such that $ P \in g \subset A$, $ P'\in g' \subset A' $ then there exist a motion mapping A to A', g to g' and P to P'
6. There is a plane A, a line g, and a point P such that $ P \in g \subset A$ then there exist four motions mapping A, g and P onto themselves, respectively, and not more than two of these motions may have every point of g as a fixed point , while there is one of them (i.e the identity) for wich every point of A is fixed.
7. There exists three points A, B, P on line g  such that P is between A and B and for every point  $ C \ (C \not = P) $ between A and B there is a point D lying between C and P for which no motion with P as fixed point can be found that will map C onto a point lying between D and P.
8. There exists a line g such that $ g \cap R' \not = \emptyset $ having the following property:
   If A,B,C are three points of $ g \cap R'$ and B is between A and C , and M is a motion that $ A^M = B . (A^{M^2} = ) B^M = C $, mapping the set of points $y$ of points between onto the set of points between B and C: then every point of g is either one of the $ A^{M^i} $ or a point of the $ y^{M^i} $ $ ( i \in Z)$

As I understand it

Axioms 1 and 5 mean that there is a motion from every line to every line

Axioms 2 to 4 that motions form a group

But then

Axiom 6 : there are 8 motions mapping A, g and P onto themselves (we are working in 3 dimensional space so have 3 degrees of freedom) or are only the direct (orientable) transformations,  motions according to this axiom?

Axiom 7: cannot follow it

Axiom 8: cannot follow it

Can anybody give some clarity in this?

This is the only set of axioms of motion I know, maybe there are simpler sets, maybe this one is more complicated because it is based on three dimensional geometry not on plane geometry.

The only other set of axioms of motion I know (Ewald "Geometry, an introduction" 1971) allready assumes the idea of isometry. (while isometry should follow from motion not the other way around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

At first sight, it seems to me that it a sort of "revised" version of [Hilbert's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) for geometry (original version: *Grundlagen der Geometrie* [1899], Engl.tr. [The Foundations of Geometry](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/17384/17384-pdf.pdf) ).

Hilbert axiomatization is organized with three primitive "objects":

> point, line, plane;

and three primitive relations:

> Betweenness: a ternary relation linking points, Lies on  (Containment), Congruence.

Axioms are grouped into:

> I.Incidence
>   II. Order
>   III. Congruence
>   IV. Parallelism
>   V. Continuity.

If we want to axiomatize [absolute geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_geometry) we have to discard the *Parallels axiom*: in this way we get the "common" part between Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries.

It seems to me that in [László Rédei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_R%C3%A9dei)'s book:

- [Foundation of Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries according to F. Klein](https://books.google.it/books?id=XMTSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA3) (1968 - German ed.1965)

among other "minor" changes, the basic difference with respect to Hilbert's approach is to replace the primitive concept of *congruence* (and its axioms set) with that of *motion*.

This approach was introduce in 1900 (indipendently from Hilbert) by [Mario Pieri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Pieri) in his: *Della geometria elementare come sistema ipotetico deduttivo: Monografia del punto e del moto* (*On elementary geometry as a hypothetical deductive system: Monograph on point and motion*).

See:

- Elena Anne Marchisotto & James Smith, [The Legacy of Mario Pieri in Geometry and Arithmetic](https://books.google.it/books?id=zZoYihwdxDwC&pg=PA157) (2007).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, still a bit confused about it all, found Pieri's postulates in Martin's "Foundations of geometry and the Non-euclidean Plane" section 15.2 pages 175 -180. Maybe best to study both sets at the same time, (both sets are about motions :) What do you make  of postulate 9? "if A, B, C are noncollinear points and D is a point on [the line] BC other than B, then a plane through A, B, D exists '''and  is a subset of a plane through A, B, C.''' " ?  but that is maybe better in a new question.

Comment: @Willemien - it seems to me that it is a sort of definition of *triangle*: all the points that belongs to the three sides of the triangle are on the same plane. I.e. the triangle is a plane figure.

Comment: I also did some more thinking about it but came to another conclusion (who will be right), I think postulate 9 means,that  trough a line and a point not on that line a there is one and only one plane (the lines BC and BD are the same line), I was just confused about a plane that is a subset of another plane, something that after some thinking, can only mean that they are the same plane. (a plane cannot be a proper subset of another plane)

Answer (score 1):

Pieri only introduces postulates as they become necessary in this development.
So if you read the axiomatization itself (which is beautiful), you could see that Pieri needs this postulate 9 to be able to make an assertion about planes similar to this theorem he had proved for lines:   If  a  and  b  are distinct points,    if it happens that  c  and  d  are distinct points of the line ab, then the lines ab  and  cd  will coincide

Regarding Pieri's postulation of the relation of being a subset: Pieri postulates only one way containment because this is just enough (coincidence being a natural consequence).  Characteristic of all his axiomatizations, Pieri wants to only postulate the minimum of what is needed.  He helps the reader see this.   In a comment after the postulate, Pieri says:  Consequently,  the plane  abc  will also be contained in the plane  abd,  for which reason the planes abc  and  abd  will coincide.